# Defining a function of two variables, where one of the variables is integrated (scipy integrate.quad)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing

I am having trouble creating a function with two variables and three parameters. I want to perform a definite (numerical) integral over one of the variables (say t), and have it spit out an array F1(x;a,b,c), i.e. an array with a value associated with each entry in x, with scalar parameters a, b, and c. Ultimately I will need to fit the parameters (a,b,c) to data using leastsq, which I have done before using simpler functions.

Code looks like this:

```
def H1(t,x,a,b,c): #integrand
    return (a function of the above, with parameters a,b,c, dummy variable to be integrated from 0 to inf t, and x)
def F1(x,a,b,c): #integrates H1: 0<t<inf
    f_int1 = integrate.quad(H1,0.,np.inf,args=(x,a,b,c)) #integrating t from 0 to inf, x is going to be an element of the array in x_data.
    return f_int1
```

Now, for example if I try to use F1 as a function:

```
F1(x_data,70.,.05,.1) #where x_data is an array of real numbers, between 0 and 500
```

I get the message:

```
quadpack.error: Supplied function does not return a valid float
```

I am hoping it will spit out an array: F1 for all the entries in x_data. If I just use a single scalar value for the first input into F1, e.g.:

```
F1(x_data[4],70.,.05,.1)
```

It spits out two numbers, which are the value of F1 at that point and the error tolerance. This looks like part of what I want, but I think I need it to work when passing an array through. So: it works for passing a single scalar value, but I need it to accept an array (and therefore make an array).

I am guessing the problem lies when I am trying to pass an array through the function as an argument. Though I am not sure what is a better way to do this? I think I have to figure out a way to do it as a function, since I will be using leastsq in the next few lines of code. (I know how to use leastsq, I think!)

Anyone have any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.integrate.quad` does not accept array-valued functions. Your best bet is to have a loop over the components (possibly with syntactic sugar of `numpy.vectorize`).